# How to feed feed_dict in tensorflow my own image data

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code:

```py
files = (glob.glob("*.jpg"))
q = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
file_name, content = reader.read(q)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [110, 110])
image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=5)
```

How do I use `image_batch` to train a model? And how can I feed images given by `image_batch` to a model, i.e. `feed_dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`tf.train.batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch) is already returning you a tensor. This API (called *input pipeline*) allows you to stream input as tensors without manually feeding numpy arrays in session.

You can use `image_batch` to build a model just like if it's a placeholder. For example, make a convolutional network:

```py
files = (glob.glob("_data/*.jpg"))
q = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
file_name, content = reader.read(q)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [110, 110])
image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=5)
# >>> image_batch
# Tensor("batch:0", shape=(5, 110, 110, 3), dtype=float32)

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 10], stddev=0.01))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.01, shape = [10]))
layer = tf.nn.conv2d(image_batch, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
pool = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer, 2, 2)
flat = tf.reshape(pool, [-1, 55 * 55 * 10])
```

Usually, you want to read examples *and* labels simultaneously and use them to define the loss function and optimize it. In session, you just run the ops, like the placeholders are already defined:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  computed_weights = sess.run(flat)
  # computed_weights: (5, 30250) array

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Note that in order to feed the data in, a coordinator has to be started.
There are a lot of things you can do using this pipeline, see [this blog-post](http://ischlag.github.io/2016/06/19/tensorflow-input-pipeline-example/) and [official tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data).